# Blazor Server and Entity Framework entity tracking issues

Tags: entity-framework-core, architecture, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm creating a basic CRUD application with Blazor, .NET 6 and EF Core 6 with lazy loading.

I've noticed a lot of integration issues when creating Web Component -> Service -> Repository -> Generic Repository pattern. The issue that bugs me the most is when creating nesting components the tracking/disposal of EF Context seems to break a lot.

I've also seen [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aaQsmkh1BkQ) on how to use it correctly and I'm not sure if that is correct that you should instantiate context every time when doing a query to DB? Also the problem rises when you want to add some custom logic to the queries, like pagination.

For example look at this code:

Generic repository GetPage method:

```
public async Task<Page<TModel>> GetPageAsync(IQueryable<TEntity> query, IPageQuery pageQuery = null, Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null)
{
  var count = await query.CountAsync();

  if (orderBy != null)
  {
    query = orderBy(query);
  }

  var entities = await query.Skip(pageQuery.PageSize * pageQuery.PageIndex).Take(pageQuery.PageSize).ToListAsync();

  var mappedEntities = mapper.Map<List<TModel>>(entities);
  return new Page<TModel>(count, mappedEntities);
}
```

Repository calling it:

```
public async Task<Page<UserModel>> GetPageAsync(UserModelQuery pageQuery = null, Func<IQueryable<User>, IOrderedQueryable<User>> orderBy = null)
{
  await using var context = await contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

  var query = context.Set<User>()
      .WhereStringLike(x => x.FirstName, pageQuery.SearchString);

  return await base.GetPageAsync(query, pageQuery, orderBy);
}
```

So, for me this mitigates the need of having generic repository since you have to pass in the main query (context.Set()) and build up the query. This way of doing it feels very unflexible but if I don't do it this way I get a lot of tracking errors from EF.

Also, currently I have a situation where I'm loading users in EditUser component and pushing it to another component where I'm editing Group of that User. Upon saving I get tracking errors regarding the Group Id that it is already being tracked.

My question is mostly a comment on this and if someone has any good Blazor Serverexperience or a repository to show the architectural approach to repository pattern with Blazor Server.
Also, an additional question would be again a comment on similar pitfalls that Blazor Serverseems to offer.

Comment: Yes, a recurring question, do research it (here). Blazor does not offer suitable DI Scopes so the recommendation is to use a DbContextFactory. Resulting in a Context (UoW) per method. Sort of pushing you to do CQRS, even in a single Crud Form.

Comment: And yes, CQRS does not play well with Lazy loading and IQueryable. Consider the Specification Pattern instead.

Comment: Hey @HH, thank you for your answer. Your "here" link is not linked can you please try again?
So you're basically saying it's worth rewriting it to Specification pattern?
What are the pitfalls with CQRS and Lazy loading?

Comment: With "here" I meant StackOverflow. But look further as well.

Comment: This is my recomendation pattern https://github.com/ctrl-alt-d/dotnetsvcs

Comment: @HH Do you mind shortly explaining why/how CQRS/Spec pattern resolve such issues? It seems like Spec pattern will also go to the generic repository, do the tracking etc. Why would that work and normal Repository pattern isn't working for example when updating an entity?

Comment: Because outside of the repository you will use detached entities. Each method is a UoW.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure if that is correct that you should instantiate context every time when doing a query to DB?

Yes, to a degree. With a web application the `DbContext` lifetime can be scoped to a request which is a convenient lifetime scope. For Blazor applications this needs to be a tad more deliberate. This can be scoping a `DbContext` instance on a per-operation basis, or scoped at a top level entry point for a request where a Repository is either passed a that scope, or can discover it. The unit of work implementation I use is the DbContextScope by Mehdi El Gueddari (EF Core fork: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Zejji.DbContextScope.EFCore6/6.0.1) where your server code uses a DbContextScopeFactory to define a scope, while the Repositories use a AmbientScopeLocator to resolve the scope the call is under to resolve an instance of a `DbContext`. (following the "discovery" route mentioned above)

I would avoid a Generic Repository pattern. The reason is that it either introduces complexity or ends up crippling the capabilities that EF can provide. (or both) Generics tend to get put in strange situations like this to "save code" or serve DRY. The key consideration for a generic is that all extended types should be treated *identically*. Every entity might share some common properties, but their uniqueness extends widely including in terms of how they will be accessed through something like a repository. When you have a Generic `List<T>` all the generic implementation cares about is what a "List" does regardless of what is within it. A `Repository<TEntity>` is not merely a collection of entities. Of course you can write it to be constrained to act like a `List<TEntity>` with inefficient common methods like "GetById", "GetAll", "Add", "Remove", etc. but that leads to inefficient querying. Attempting to introduce sorting, projection, eager loading, etc. gets particularly complicated or it happens in memory which is really expensive. Or it can be set up as a facade to a `DbSet<TEntiy>` which will be an extremely anemic wrapper of `IQueryable<TEntity>` where it has no knowledge of specifics of that entity/aggregate which begs the question "what is the point?".

To help manage common rules it helps if the repository implementation is specific to the type(s) it will be focused on dealing with. So for instance if I have an aggregate root where I have service classes for dealing with that set of related objects I would have a single repository defined for that aggregate root and related entities. In a web application sense I will have an OrderController, not try to write a `Controller<T>` with a `Controller<Order>`, so I write an OrderRepository that serves all of the needs of the OrderController. Same goes for Blazor, so if using something like an MVC pattern for the Blazor app, Repositories can serve a specific controller. If MVVM then a repository can serve a top-level VM or set of VMs where there is a logical boundary for the domain.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I feel a bit reluctant towards using a library for such "simple" cases. I'm literally trying to build a simple CRUD here and I'm looking for the easiest (non conflicting) way of doing it. I've seen a lot of people mentioning Spec pattern or CQRS so I might lean towards that.